# Как в 1С объявить глобальную переменную в модуле формы?

Tags: 1с

Подскажите люди добрые!

Мне необходима глобальная переменная булевского типа, доступная в модуле формы на время существования самой формы.

в модуле формы объявляю:

```
перем БесплатнаяДоставка;

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПриОткрытии(Отказ)
    БесплатнаяДоставка = Ложь;
КонецПроцедуры

&НаКлиенте
Процедура СуммаПриИзменении(Отказ)
       Если (Объект.Сумма > 1000) И (БесплатнаяДоставка = Ложь) Тогда
            ............
       КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры
```

Ругается на переменную **БесплатнаяДоставка** , пишет "переменная не определена".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Перед описанием переменной обязательно
> должна быть указана директива
> компиляции (&НаКлиенте или
> &НаСервере).
>
> Если используется директива компиляции
> &НаКлиенте, то такая переменная будет
> существовать с момента создания формы
> до момента ее закрытия. Причем только
> в клиентской части формы. Из серверных
> процедур формы она доступна не будет.

(с) Максим Радченко, 1С. [Ветка форума](http://devtrainingforum.v8.1c.ru/forum/thread.jsp?id=562822).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте объявить переменную в модуле формы с экспорт, и потом получая форму по уникальному идентификатору к ней обращатся. Если не секрет, вам оно зачем?